# User input in cronjob

Tags: shell-script, cron, password, gpg, input

I have created a script which calls another script.I'm implementing this via below cronjob

```
    55 12 * * * cd /backup2 && ./script2.sh
```

The another script ,I'm calling(restore1.sh) requires user input(password). However, when running it via cronjob ,it's not asking for any user input. script2.sh calling restore.sh script.Inside restore1.sh script,it needs a password to proceed further. The cronjob should prompt for password. Any way to achieve this.

Here is content for script2.sh file.

```
    ##################script2.sh
    #!/bin/bash

    sh ./restore1.sh


   sh ./restore.sh $v1
```

Here is content for restore1.sh script.

```
######################### restore1.sh
  echo "Provide pss for restoration"
   read pass
 echo $pass
  v1=`gpg --yes  --batch --passphrase=$pass  ws_20190717.sql.gpg`

  echo $v1
```

Comment: ... and where would that cronjob prompt for a pattern? There is no standard output like in a shell attached.

Comment: Not knowing what your script does, it is difficult to give a good answer, but reading the password from a protected file if standard input is not a terminal would be one approach.

Comment: How (or to what) do your provide that password if you run it normally?

Comment: @Panki,@Kusalananda,@muru -I have attached script. Please let me know if require more details

Comment: `gpg2` allows for reading the passphrase from a file (`--passphrase-file somefile`). I'm not sure what earlier versions of GnuPG are able to do.